# API Gateway custom domain certificate error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to set up a regional API gateway with a custom domain, and I'm hitting a problem involving SSL certificates. Here's what I've done:

- Using ACM, created a certificate for vitalservices-3.docriot.com.
- In API Gateway, created a regional custom domain name--vitalservices-3.docriot.com--assigned the vitalservices-3.docriot.com certificate to it, and added a base path mapping from "/" to "vitalservices-3:prod".
- In the Route53 hosted zone for docriot.com, created a CNAME record mapping vitalservices-3.docriot.com to 82cgbm6s93.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. This record has a latency-based routing policy, but it is, for now, the only record for vitalservices-3.docriot.com.

When I run

```
curl https://82cgbm6s93.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod
```

I get

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

which is what I expect, as the API requires Cognito authentication. I get the same message when I ignore certificate errors using the "-k" option and run

```
curl https://vitalservices-3.docriot.com -k
```

But if I drop the -k and run

```
curl https://vitalservices-3.docriot.com
```

I get

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain . . .
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I was just using curl on my OS X box because I assumed it was a simpler way of illustrating the error. I get similar behavior when I access those URLs in my Chrome browser. If enter https://vitalservices-3.docriot.com, I get the red warning triangle in the URL bar and the page saying, "Attackers might be trying to steal your information . . . ". Then, if I choose the option to view the page anyways, the browser displays a page with the text "{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}", just as when I use "curl -k". Thus I don't think the problem is that my machine doesn't trust a certificate authority.

I've attached a screenshot of what I see when I click "Not Secure" in the url bar and look at the certificate info.[image]

Comment: Did you create a manage certificate in ACM or did you upload one? Does the machine you're testing on trust Amazon's root CA? This question would be much easier to solve if you shared the actual domain.

Comment: I used ACM to create a certificate for vitalservices-3.docriot.com. I don't think it's a CA issues, as I get the same behavior when I enter the urls in Chrome on my OS X box.

Comment: In the browser I get `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` because the certificate it serves is for `*.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. Did you try with `A` record aliased to your API as the documentation suggests?

Comment: Which documentation, and wouldn't 82cgbm6s93.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com need a fixed IP address for an A record to work?

Comment: It will be an aliased record, so Route53 will figure out the IP from the source. The documentation is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-regional-api-custom-domain-create.html).

Comment: @ChristopherSimmons, you are not pointing your DNS record to the correct endpoint, I don't think.  If the API is edge-optimized, your target will be a `cloudfront.net` hostname; if it's a regional endpoint, it should have a `d-` prefix and at the beginning of the `execute-api` hostname.  Show us the config from the Custom Domain Names screen in the API Gateway console.

Comment: kichik and Michael provided the answer. I changed Route53 to use an aliased A record, and I also changed the endpoint to the one with the "d-" prefix, and the certificate error is gone now. Thanks much.

Comment: For anyone still following this, I am not using Route53 for DNS and did not need to create an alias A record. I simply had to use the "d-" prefix endpoint instead of the main (default?) API endpoint that AWS generates. The "d-" prefix endpoint is found in the API Gateway console within your custom domain configuration settings.

Comment: I made the same mistake by pointing the 'API Gateway Invoke URL'. Resolved by pointing 'API Gateway domain' name instead. Appreciate all of you guys who suggested this.

Answer (score 2):

The error that curl is displaying is not very specific and applies to a number of certificate issues. In your case, you are probably missing the file `cacert.pem`, which is a bundle of certificates of public Certificate Authorities from Mozilla.

You can download cacert.pem from CURL's web site:

[cacert.pem](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)

[More information about cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)

Comment: See my edit. My guess is that Chrome isn't missing a certificate authorities file.

Comment: Remember that your certificate must match the host name of the site that you are accessing. Since you are masking this information I cannot see what url you are using.

Comment: The certificate shown in the screenshot does not match my custom url, but I have no control over that certificate. It and the domain attached to it are owned by AWS. I think that what's happening is 1) I enter my custom URL into the browser. 2) The browser sees the CNAME record and then goes to the AWS url instead. 3) The browser gets the certificate associated with the AWS url. 4) The browser sees that the original URL that I entered doesn't match that certificate. There must be some way around this problem, but associating my own certificate with the custom domain seems to have no effect.

Comment: And I accidentally did place the real url in my post, so I may as well point it out: https://vitalservices-3.docriot.com

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure two things.

1. API Gateway is the same as your custom domain name. Regional or edge.
2. You have right DNS configured for the domain.

Your cert in ACM should show the same allowed domain as your API gateway custom domain.

We had the same problem and the issue was that the DNS record was pointing to the API Gateway endpoint. Not to the Target Domain Name endpoint of the Custom Domain Names. Because of this, the cert was coming for *.execute-.amazonaws.com.

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced with the same issue. I found one of the common mistake that people are doing is that you have an `A` record in your hosted zone pointing to the domain name from your **stage url**, which is **incorrect**.

`A` record should point to the **API Gateway Domain name** that you receive when create custom domain name mapping in API Gateway console.

[image]

Correct hosted zone config:

[image]

After that certificates turns valid and browser displays correct `Issued To` value

[image]

Comment: thank you, that is my case. I was pointing **Route53 A record** to the **API Gateway Invoke URL** and it caused the issue with the SSL certificate and returned 403 when I tried to implement mutual TLS authentication. After that I recreated **A record** and pointed it to the **API Gateway domain name** and it worked.

Comment: I made the same mistake by pointing the 'API Gateway Invoke URL'. Resolved by pointing 'API Gateway domain' name instead. Appreciate all of you guys who suggested this.

Answer (score 0):

Certificate you chose from dropdown in Custom Domain of API Gateway does not satisfy dns you're hitting.
Only vitalservices-3.docriot.com or *.docriot.com is valid from ACM. Try changing ssl with the one mentioned will resolve this.